# KeyHandler is getting behind on KeyEvent?

Tags: keylistener

FOUND THE SOLUTION ! 
I made a List that takes in all key's typed, and outputs them when needed !
the problem was my main game state wasnt updating fast enough. i hope i helped at least someone out there :)

```
package base.main.keyhandler;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class KeyHandler {
    public static final int NUM_KEYS = 25;

    public static int keyCode;

    public static boolean anyKey;
    public static boolean prevAnyKey;

    public static boolean keyState[] = new boolean[NUM_KEYS];
    public static boolean prevKeyState[] = new boolean[NUM_KEYS];

    public static int[] registeredKeys = new int[]{
        KeyEvent.VK_Z,
        KeyEvent.VK_Q,
        KeyEvent.VK_S,
        KeyEvent.VK_D,

        KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, //Attack
        KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,//Accept
        KeyEvent.VK_E,//inventory
        KeyEvent.VK_F, //interact

        KeyEvent.VK_T,//for console shouldn't be changeable. maybe for talking later ?
        KeyEvent.VK_B,//for bounding boxes. shouldn't be changeable

        KeyEvent.VK_1,
        KeyEvent.VK_2,
        KeyEvent.VK_3,
        KeyEvent.VK_4,
        KeyEvent.VK_5,
        KeyEvent.VK_6,
        KeyEvent.VK_7,
        KeyEvent.VK_8,
        KeyEvent.VK_9,
        KeyEvent.VK_M,//Place button for xbox controllers 

        KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE,
        KeyEvent.VK_N, //escape button 2, for controllers only
    };

    public static int UP = 0;
    public static int LEFT = 1;
    public static int DOWN = 2;
    public static int RIGHT = 3;

    public static int SPACE = 4;
    public static int ENTER = 5;
    public static int INVENTORY = 6;
    public static int INTERACT = 7;

    public static int T = 8;
    public static int B = 9;

    public static int ONE = 10;
    public static int TWO = 11;
    public static int THREE = 12;
    public static int FOUR = 13;
    public static int FIVE = 14;
    public static int SIX = 15;
    public static int SEVEN = 16;
    public static int EIGHT = 17;
    public static int NINE = 18;
    public static int PLACE = 19;

    public static int ESCAPE = 20;

    public static int ESCAPE2 = 21;

    public static int ANYKEY = 22;

    public static boolean anyKeyPress() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_KEYS; i++)
            if (keyState[i])
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static String keyPressed(int i, String string){
        //      System.out.println(string);

        if(typed.isEmpty())
            return string;

        System.out.println(typed.size() + " " + typed.get(0)+ " " + string);

        if(keyState[ANYKEY] && !prevKeyState[ANYKEY] || typed.size() > 0){

            String s = typed.get(0);

            System.out.println("key passing " + s);

            //          String s = KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode);

            if(s.length() == 1)
                string +=s;
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE && string.length() > 0){
                String s2 = string.substring(0, string.length()-1);
                string = s2;
            }
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
                string+=" ";
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UNDERSCORE)
                string+="_";

            typed.remove(0);
            typed.trimToSize();

            //          System.out.println("key typed "+s);
            //          System.out.println("string returned " + string);
        }
        return string.toLowerCase();
    }

    public static boolean isPressed(int i) {
        return keyState[i] && !prevKeyState[i] ;
    }

    public static boolean isReleased(int i) {
        return !keyState[i] && prevKeyState[i];
    }


    public static boolean isValidationKeyPressed(){
        return (keyState[SPACE] && !prevKeyState[SPACE]) || (keyState[ENTER] && !prevKeyState[ENTER]);
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> typed = new ArrayList<>();


    public static void keySet(int i, boolean b){

        keyCode = i;

        if(b)
            typed.add(KeyEvent.getKeyText(i));

        if (i == registeredKeys[UP])
            keyState[UP] = b;
        else if (i == registeredKeys[LEFT])
            keyState[LEFT] = b;
        else if (i == registeredKeys[RIGHT])
            keyState[RIGHT] = b;
        else if (i == registeredKeys[DOWN])
            keyState[DOWN] = b;

        else if (i == registeredKeys[SPACE])
            keyState[SPACE] = b;

        else if (i == registeredKeys[ENTER])
            keyState[ENTER] = b;

        else if (i == registeredKeys[ESCAPE])
            keyState[ESCAPE] = b;

        else if (i == registeredKeys[T])
            keyState[T] = b;

        else if (i == registeredKeys[INVENTORY])
            keyState[INVENTORY] = b;

        else if (i == registeredKeys[B])
            keyState[B] = b;

        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_1){
            keyState[ONE] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_2){
            keyState[TWO] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_3){
            keyState[THREE] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_4){
            keyState[FOUR] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_5){
            keyState[FIVE] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_6){
            keyState[SIX] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_7){
            keyState[SEVEN] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_8){
            keyState[EIGHT] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_9){
            keyState[NINE] = b;
        }
        else if(i == registeredKeys[INTERACT]){
            keyState[INTERACT] = b;
        }

        //xbox only.
        else if(i == registeredKeys[PLACE]){
            keyState[PLACE] = b;
        }
        else if(i == registeredKeys[ESCAPE2]){
            keyState[ESCAPE2] = b;
        }

        keyState[ANYKEY] = b;
    }

    public static void update() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_KEYS; i++)
            prevKeyState[i] = keyState[i];
    }
}
```

So, i've been working on this small game for a while.
The game started lagging, so I wrote another game loop which handles updating every tick, and can skip frames if needed.

I've recently added a console into the game, in which i can type some commands to debug several aspects of the game without needing to wait.

I've then noticed that only half of the keys that I typed where getting print out in the game....

So after debugging :

```
    Key typed H
key passing H
Key typed E
key passing E
Key typed L
key passing L
Key typed L
key passing L
Key typed O
key passing O
Key typed Space
Key typed W
key passing W
Key typed O
Key typed R
key passing R
Key typed L
key passing L
Key typed D
```

every key should have a typed, passed to it, which isn't always the case...
(it should have printed hello world, but it printed hellowrl)

FYI : Key typed is printed directly in the 'keyPressed' method

```
@Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
        KeyHandler.keySet(key.getKeyCode(), true);
        System.out.println("Key typed "+KeyEvent.getKeyText(key.getKeyCode()));
    }
```

I've looked up tutorials and other people's keyhandler problem, but none of them seem to relate. what am I doing wrong ??

here's the code from the keyhandler.

(if i need to post anything else, please ask, and I'll edit this post !)

```
package base.main.keyhandler;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class KeyHandler {
    public static final int NUM_KEYS = 25;

    public static int keyCode;

    public static boolean anyKey;
    public static boolean prevAnyKey;

    public static boolean keyState[] = new boolean[NUM_KEYS];
    public static boolean prevKeyState[] = new boolean[NUM_KEYS];

    public static int[] registeredKeys = new int[]{
        KeyEvent.VK_Z,
        KeyEvent.VK_Q,
        KeyEvent.VK_S,
        KeyEvent.VK_D,

        KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, //Attack
        KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,//Accept
        KeyEvent.VK_E,//inventory
        KeyEvent.VK_F, //interact

        KeyEvent.VK_T,//for console shouldn't be changeable. maybe for talking later ?
        KeyEvent.VK_B,//for bounding boxes. shouldn't be changeable

        KeyEvent.VK_1,
        KeyEvent.VK_2,
        KeyEvent.VK_3,
        KeyEvent.VK_4,
        KeyEvent.VK_5,
        KeyEvent.VK_6,
        KeyEvent.VK_7,
        KeyEvent.VK_8,
        KeyEvent.VK_9,
        KeyEvent.VK_M,//Place button for xbox controllers 

        KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE,
        KeyEvent.VK_N, //escape button 2, for controllers only
    };

    public static int UP = 0;
    public static int LEFT = 1;
    public static int DOWN = 2;
    public static int RIGHT = 3;

    public static int SPACE = 4;
    public static int ENTER = 5;
    public static int INVENTORY = 6;
    public static int INTERACT = 7;

    public static int T = 8;
    public static int B = 9;

    public static int ONE = 10;
    public static int TWO = 11;
    public static int THREE = 12;
    public static int FOUR = 13;
    public static int FIVE = 14;
    public static int SIX = 15;
    public static int SEVEN = 16;
    public static int EIGHT = 17;
    public static int NINE = 18;
    public static int PLACE = 19;

    public static int ESCAPE = 20;

    public static int ESCAPE2 = 21;

    public static int ANYKEY = 22;

    public static boolean anyKeyPress() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_KEYS; i++)
            if (keyState[i])
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static String keyPressed(int i, String string){
        if(keyState[ANYKEY] && !prevKeyState[ANYKEY]){
            System.out.println("key passing " + KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode));

            String s = KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode);
            if(s.length() == 1)
                string +=s;
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE && string.length() > 0){
                String s2 = string.substring(0, string.length()-1);
                string = s2;
            }
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
                string+=" ";
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UNDERSCORE)
                string+="_";

//          System.out.println("key typed "+s);
//          System.out.println("string returned " + string);
        }
        return string.toLowerCase();
    }

    public static boolean isPressed(int i) {
        return keyState[i] && !prevKeyState[i] ;
    }

    public static boolean isReleased(int i) {
        return !keyState[i] && prevKeyState[i];
    }


    public static boolean isValidationKeyPressed(){
        return (keyState[SPACE] && !prevKeyState[SPACE]) || (keyState[ENTER] && !prevKeyState[ENTER]);
    }

    public static void keySet(int i, boolean b){

        keyCode = i;

        if (i == registeredKeys[UP])
            keyState[UP] = b;
        else if (i == registeredKeys[LEFT])
            keyState[LEFT] = b;
        else if (i == registeredKeys[RIGHT])
            keyState[RIGHT] = b;
        else if (i == registeredKeys[DOWN])
            keyState[DOWN] = b;

        else if (i == registeredKeys[SPACE])
            keyState[SPACE] = b;

        else if (i == registeredKeys[ENTER])
            keyState[ENTER] = b;

        else if (i == registeredKeys[ESCAPE])
            keyState[ESCAPE] = b;

        else if (i == registeredKeys[T])
            keyState[T] = b;

        else if (i == registeredKeys[INVENTORY])
            keyState[INVENTORY] = b;

        else if (i == registeredKeys[B])
            keyState[B] = b;

        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_1){
            keyState[ONE] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_2){
            keyState[TWO] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_3){
            keyState[THREE] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_4){
            keyState[FOUR] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_5){
            keyState[FIVE] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_6){
            keyState[SIX] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_7){
            keyState[SEVEN] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_8){
            keyState[EIGHT] = b;
        }
        else if (i == KeyEvent.VK_9){
            keyState[NINE] = b;
        }
        else if(i == registeredKeys[INTERACT]){
            keyState[INTERACT] = b;
        }

        //xbox only.
        else if(i == registeredKeys[PLACE]){
            keyState[PLACE] = b;
        }
        else if(i == registeredKeys[ESCAPE2]){
            keyState[ESCAPE2] = b;
        }

        keyState[ANYKEY] = b;
    }

    public static void update() {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_KEYS; i++)
            prevKeyState[i] = keyState[i];
    }
}
```

thanks.